# I'm facing problem with operator overloading during constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Here I've implemented a class called Vector and tried to overload = operator with a parameter initialized_list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T* arr;
    int  _size;
    int capacity;

public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    Vector<T>& operator = (const initializer_list<T>& l);
    
};
template<class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator = (const initializer_list<T>& l)
{
   
    _size=capacity=l.size();
    arr=new T[l.size()];
    return *this;
}
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    _size=0;
    capacity=0;

}
template<class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] arr;
}
```

In this implementation if I run with the code below it works fine.

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int>v;
    v={1,2,3};
}
```

But if I want to run with this code below it shows `error: could not convert '{1, 2, 3}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Vector<int>'`

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int>v={1,2,3};
}
```

How can I fix this problem to make it work as the code above?

Comment: The 2nd case is construction not assignment.  Write a constructor similar to the assignment operator.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have templated the size and capacity variable also ?

Comment: @ThivinAnandh it was a mistake.

Comment: Just to let you know, the `v={1,2,3};` part is still not copying the actual data , rather its only creating a space for an array which is the size of the intializer list.